# How did méchant get its meaning?

Tags: étymologie, préfixes

The definition of méchant is "mean", as in "mean-spirited", but how did it get this meaning? A [quick search of its etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9chant) shows that it probably derives from the Old French verb *cheoir*, which means to "fall out" or "become detached". I can see how mean-spiritedness is a kind of falling out... but is that the connection which led méchant to acquire its meaning?

Comment: Let me add that the prefix "mé-" means "in a bad, negative way" (ex: médire, mécontent, méconnaissable). So mé+chéant would mean "who falls in a bad way", that leans a bit towards the current meaning. Look also at the French article of wiktionary: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9chant#.C3.89tymologie

Comment: @Greg Ah, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: *[Mécréant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9cr%C3%A9ant)* follows a similar pattern.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah! So that's how the English word "miscreant" gets its meaning. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The prefix "mé-" means "in a bad, negative way" (ex: médire, mécontent, méconnaissable). So mé+chéant would mean "who falls in a bad way", that leans a bit towards the current meaning. Look also at [the French article of wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9chant#.C3.89tymologie).